# Insert method in custom vector class in c++

Tags: c++, vector

right now I'm making a custom vector class in c++:

```
class Vector {
    size_t size =  0;
    size_t cap  =  2;
    T*     arr;
```

One of the functions I need to make is

```
void insert(size_t ind, const T e[], size_t sz)
```

which is supposed to insert elements of the passed array e of size sz to the vector, starting from the position indicated by index ind. If the current capacity is sufficient, elements from position ind are shifted to the right to make room for new elements from the array e. If the capacity is too small to accommodate for old and new elements, a new array arr is allocated with capacity twice as big as necessary. Old and new elements are then copied to the new array at appropriate positions and the old one is deleted.
The code I have right now is this:

```
void insert(size_t ind, const T e[], size_t sz){
        if (ind >= size) error("range error");
        for(int i=0,ind;sz>=0;ind++,sz--){
            arr[ind+1]=arr[ind];
            arr[ind]=e[i];
        }
        if(cap<sz){
            T* a;
            MyVector v = new MyVector(0,2*(size+sz),a);
            memmove(arr,memcpy(a,e,sz),sz);
            arr=v;
        }

    }
```

My biggest issue is how to check if the capacity is enough and if my use of memmove and memcopy is appropriate.

Comment: You start with an *uninitialized* `arr` pointer, but still say that the capacity is `2`. Are you actually allocating memory in any of your constructors?

Comment: And you need to check the size and capacity *before* you're trying to insert an element, otherwise you will go out of bounds. And besides, you have a memory leak, since you allocate a new `MyVector` object, but you never `delete` it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, I'm not

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is it possible to check if I'm not going out of bounds by putting if(sz<=(cap-size)) before the loop?

Comment: No, it's not sufficient to use `memcpy` here. A simple example where this would fail to produce objects in a valid state would be a type `Demo` containing a member variable `m_self` initialized with `this` in the constructor; in this case I define the object pointed to by `Demo* ptr;` to be in a valid state if `ptr->m_self == ptr` which is not the case after working with memcpy; You cannot assume for arbitrary objects that they are in a valid state, if you don't execute a constructor.

Comment: @PppLll There are tons of questions on StackOverflow whose answers show the proper way to implement a custom Vector class with insertions. Have you read any of them yet?